# nginx reverse proxy to different applications based on an index in the host name

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

Previously, I had a single staging environment reachable behind a DNS `staging.example.com/`. Behind this address is a nginx proxy with the following config. Note that my proxy either redirects

- To a (s3 behind) cloudfront distribution (app1)
- To a loadbalancer by forwarding the host name (and let's consider my ALB is able to pick the appropriate app based on the host name)  (app2)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name
      staging.example.com
  ;

  location / {
    try_files /maintenance.html @app1;
  }

  location ~ /(faq|about_us|terms|press|...) {
      try_files /maintenance.html @app2;
  }

  [...] # Lots of similar config than redirects either to app1 or app2

  # Application hosted on s3 + CloudFront
  location @app1 {
    proxy_set_header Host app1-staging.example.com;
    proxy_pass http://d2c72vkj8qy1kv.cloudfront.net;
  }

  # Application hosted behind a load balancer
  location @app2 {
    proxy_set_header Host app2-staging.example.internal;
    proxy_set_header X-ALB-Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass https://staging.example.internal;
  }
}
```

Now, my team needs a couple more staging environments. We are not yet ready to transition to docker deployments (the ultimate goal of being able to spawn a complete infra per branch that we need to test... is a bit overkill given our team size) and I'm trying to pull out some tricks instead so we can easily get a couple more staging environments **using roughly the same nginx config**.

Assume I have a created a few more DNS names with a `index_i` like `staging1.example.com`, `staging2.example.com`. So my nginx proxy will receive requests with a host header that looks like `staging#{index_i}.example.com`

What I'm thinking of doing :

- For my s3 + Cloudfront app, I'm thinking of nesting my files under `[bucket_id]/#{index_i}/[app1_files]` (previously they were directly in the root folder `[bucket_id]/[app1_files]`)
- For my load balancer app, let's assume my load balancer knows where to dispatch `https://staging#{iindex_i}.example.com` requests.

I'm trying to pull something like this

```
# incoming host : staging{index_i}.example.com`
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name
      staging.example.com
      staging1.example.com 
      staging2.example.com # I can list them manually, but is it possible to have something like `staging*.example.com` ?
  ;
[...]
location @app1 {
    proxy_set_header Host app1-staging$index_i.example.com; # Note the extra index_i here
    proxy_pass http://d2c72vkj8qy1kv.cloudfront.net/$index_i; # Here proxy_passing to a subfolder named index_i
  }

  location @app2 {
    proxy_set_header Host app2-staging$index_i.example.internal; # Note the extra index_i here
    proxy_set_header X-ALB-Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://staging$index_i.example.internal; # Here I am just forwarding the host header basically
  }
```

So ultimately my questions are
 - When my nginx server receives a connexion, can I extract the `index_i` variable from the request host header (using maybe some regex ?)
 - If yes, how can effectively implement the app1 and app2 blocks with `index_i` ?

Comment: Could you please explain the downvote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at several other questions, I was able to come up with this config that works perfectly: it's possible to extract the said variable using a regex in the host name.

On the downside, for my static single page applications, to make it work with S3, I had to create one bucket per "staging index" (because of the way static hosting on S3 works with website hosting / a single index.html to be used on 404). This made it in turn impossible to work with a single Cloudfront distribution in front of my (previously single) s3.

Here is example of using a proxy with a create-react-app frontend and server-side rendering behind an ALB

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name ~^staging(?<staging_index>\d*).myjobglasses.com$

  location @create-react-app-frontend {
      proxy_pass http://staging$staging_index.example.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com;
  }

  location @server-side-rendering-app {
      # Now Amazon Application Load Balancer can redirect traffic based on ANY HTTP header
      proxy_set_header EXAMPLE-APP old-frontend;
      proxy_pass https://staging$staging_index.myjobglasses.com;
  }
```